# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Estimating Dialog

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

My boss has recently tasked me with developing an estimating form in Dynamics CRM Online for use by his sales team. The idea is that his sales team can enter the parameters into a dialog and have Dynamics spit out a rough estimate for the cost of the project. Sales team members need to be able to do this while on site at a customer's location.

I have no idea about anything with Dynamics. I could easily do this in Excel VBA and make it look nice. I could develop my own app in C# or Java. But the ideal is to integrate this into Dynamics CRM with existing opportunities and associated tools. I've looked at Dynamics on my boss' monitor and I've poked some of the existing dialogs on our old on-premises Dynamics server with a long stick.

Is this kind of application even possible with Dynamics Online? We'd need to take user input, query the product database for pricing info from that input, and do some fancy arithmetic to spit out a number and ideally save the data in some way associated with an opportunity. This is a flooring company, and I envision an estimating tool where you can dynamically add a room to a list in a dialog, specify the size of the room in two text entry boxes (length x width), and select a type of flooring and substrate from a combination of radial buttons and drop down boxes, and finally have a price displayed for that room with a cumulative price displayed for each additional room added to the list.

Somebody please tell me if this is possible and where I can go for some resources on developing for Dynamics CRM to teach me how to do it. Help!

:edit:
Essentially the current manual estimating process is rather laborious and takes a couple of days turnaround. Sales reps run through a checklist and submit a form to the office with information about the size of the job, substrate, and the products to be installed and then a human operator manually calculates an estimate with that information. An automated system should allow sales reps to input some basic information and get a rough estimate in minutes while on site with the customer making the sale.

At its most basic, the application must be able to accept user input for the substrate under the flooring, the new flooring type, and square footage for each type of flooring. With that information, it needs to query price information from a database and then calculate an estimate for the project. It needs to be available online via mobile devices (tablets or possibly phones) for sales reps who are on location with a customer.

Beyond that, if we can have it save the estimate into an existing opportunity or create a new opportunity within Dynamics CRM, that would be great.

Comment: it's more a design question and is necessary to know the exact requirements to choose the right way to implement the solution, but I will exclude a dialog, maybe a silverlight Web Resource is more suitable in this scenario

Comment: I added some more details to the OP. As I said, I could code this easily in VBA or Java, but I know nothing about Dynamics and my web dev skills are not noteworthy. Any help or URLs to resources on how to develop for Dynamics would be great. I've already dug around the MSDN site for Dynamics development, but it's of little help to a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid learning specific CRM development features, you can add web resource, it could be HTML page, add link to the web resource on CRM page and using only javascript populate field you need with any data you need.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a lot of recent experience in web development.
How much integration can I get with the web resource? Can I access CRM database information including contacts, opportunities, and product lists?

Answer (score 1):

This could definitely be accomplished with the out-of-the-box features. It wouldn't work exactly like you envisioned, but it would be close.

You'd need to set up the Product Catalog in CRM. Each Product could be one of your flooring types or substrates. The Pricing List for each Product would show how much 1 square foot of each type of flooring costs.

When Sales creates an Opportunity, they can add Product Line Items for each different type of flooring, along with a Quantity (which would be total Sq Feet for that item).  CRM would then calculate the Line Item and the total Opportunity from the Price List and Product Catalog. Each line item total can also be discounted or overridden from the Price List, if necessary.

Once the customer wants a Quote, you can convert the Opportunity into a Quote, and all line items are copied over. You could then print this out and give it to the customer.

If the customer accepts the Quote, you can convert the Quote into an Order. Again, all line items are copied over.

Finally, you can create multiple invoices for an Order, and again line items are copied over and you can override prices or line items if necessary for billing.

There are lots of good video tutorials out there on setting up the Product Catalog, Price Lists, Discount Lists, etc. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response :) I haven't had much luck finding tutorial videos, but part of that is not knowing what to search for. How would I create a form with radial buttons and checkboxes and dropdown boxes to make a simple interface for sales reps to use that would automatically populate the line items on the opportunity?

Comment: Creating a form like that will definitely involve custom web resources as paramosh says in his answer. My answer is about just using the out-of-the-box features to accomplish what you want. It may not be as user-friendly, but you could at least get going with a minimal investment. From there, you'd just be building a simpler user interface on top of these out-of-the-box features, so it wouldn't be a wasted effort to start that way. I'm a fan of starting simple and growing into more complexity. :)

Comment: Also, here is a nice video on the Product Catalog: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6itGW_wJvM

And here's a few on the Opportunity->Quote->Order->Invoice process:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXOBZp78tbQ
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNcO0NtSOXE
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEXm14DJSRg

Comment: Thanks for the videos. The current workflow includes manually filling in the line items, though right now we don't have the product catalog added to CRM yet. This client is at the "growing into complexity" step and I just don't yet have the experience to make it happen.

Comment: We'd be happy to help if you are interested in experienced resources for CRM! http://www.nexrm.com